# Access redis database in docker compose

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose

I have a Django app that I want to move to docker. A redis dump.rdb file is in the root directory of the project, and contains data needed for the app to work. I normally start that by running redis-server while in the same directory. How can I move this configuration to docker? I know I can use volumes and suspect I need to mount my code folder as one, but will that cause other issues? Here is my current docker setup:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:2.7.14
 ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
 RUN mkdir /code
 WORKDIR /code
 ADD . /code/
 ADD requirements /requirements
 RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.3
    expose:
      - "5432"
    volumes:
       - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  redis:
    image: redis:3.2.6
    expose:
      - "6379"
    volumes:
       - ./code
  redis_cache:
    image: redis:3.2.6
    expose:
      - "6379"
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:5.6.6
    expose:
      - "9200"
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
    - DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres@db/postgres
    - ENVIRONMENT=development
    - REDIS_URL=redis://redis:6379
    - REDIS_CACHE_URL=redis://redis_cache:6379
    - ELASTIC_ENDPOINT=elasticsearch:9200
    env_file: docker.env
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
      - elasticsearch
    volumes:
      - .:/code
volumes:
  pgdata: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways. What do you need to prefer depends on your project and what kind of information stored in `dump.rds` file.

1. you can create your custom `redis` image with `dump.rds` file inside. Then you need to push it to your repository.
2. You can, as you mention above, mount volume from source code. But I prefer mount not whole `code` directory but mount only `redis` directory which stores data intended for Redis.
3. Also, you can create some migration script in `web` container. It may create some data in `redis` container as well as in `db` container.

Comment: Hello. Can you expand on #2 a bit? I've tried implementing this but cannot figure it out.